# Hair - Make straight edges

Tags: particles, hair

[image]

Is there a way to make the hair strands become totally straight ( just like the lines ) and hence get a sharp hair edge with no patches? Thanks

Comment: in particle edit mode you can cut and remove hair

Comment: @AllenSimpson I tried doing that, but the unevenness still remains. Even with 0 endpoint value it won't get straight.